# How to write a service which consumes 2 different types of objects but have a single endpoint?

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

How to write a service which consumes 2 different types of objects but have a single endpoint ?

/hello is the endpoint I should be able to handle Class Hello1 and Class Hello2 in that...both having different parameters.

```
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public BaseResponseDTO geteula(@RequestBody Hello1 request) {}

@CrossOrigin
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public BaseResponseDTO geteula(@RequestBody Hello2 request) {}
```

Above is what I need actually...but it needs to be a single endpoint.

Comment: What do you mean by `handle Class Hello1 and Class Hello2`. You can simply have one controller class and then two difference service classes Hello1 and Hello2 and let the controller talk to them

Comment: Have updated the post..please verify. Hope its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do this I guess you can inhert your `Hello1` and `Hello2` class from some abstract class `Hello`, for example, and use it as a parameter. Also you should take advange of Jackson `@JsonSubTypes` and `@JsonTypeInfo` annotations. But in this case you should also send additional property from your client so Jackson nows what exaclty implementation class it should instantiate. For example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Hello1.class, name = "hello1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Hello2.class, name = "hello2")
})
public abstract class Hello { 
   ...
}
```

Then extend this class with your classes:

```
public class Hello1 extends Hello { 
   ...
}

public class Hello2 extends Hello { 
   ...
}
```

And your controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public BaseResponseDTO geteula(@RequestBody Hello request) {
    if (request instanceof Hello1) {
        // some logic
    }
    if (request instanceof Hello2) {
        // some logic
    }
    ...
}
```

Please note, that in this case, your JSON should include type property as defined ablove `property = "type"` (you can name it whatever you like):

```
{"type" : "hello1", .....}
```

Comment: Can we use java generics in the request object ?

Comment: @LintoKA, how do you mean? Can you set an example?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please learn how to format code; I did it for you.
2. What is `@CrossOrigin` - AFAIK, Spring doesn't have any such annotation.
3. Don't do this: Create separate methods.

If for some reason, your life depends on writing convoluted code, you can inject the `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter to your method and convert the request body into one of the 2 types. You'll have to figure out what type the body is based on something in the request.

**Edit**:
I see that Spring has, in fact, introduced a `@CrossOrigin` annotation. I stand corrected on #2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to have two methods which respond to the same request (By same request I mean the same routing path and the same method).

What you can do is to create a single entry for the "hello" POST request, and make a DTO object which contains all the members of `Hello1` plus all the members of `Hell2`. Inside the entry method you write the code to determine the type of the request, and do the replies respectively.

Comment: This works but I too feel its dirty. Any other way to handle this ?

I dont have handle of the location when the service call is made.